# Disable dropdown list without any event

Tags: java, html, scriptlet

I have one jsp and want to disable dropdown list using scriplet without any onclick method or event in dropdown menu

```
         <%
                boolean something= true;
                if(something){
      // here I want to get plc1 using id and want to disable it if it is true
                }else{
//do some thing
}
            %>
```

my dropdown html code is here

```
<td bgcolor='' align="center" ><select id = "plc1" name="place1" onclick="this.parentNode.style.backgroundColor = this.value">
                     <option value='red'>Park here</option>
                     <option value='green'>Cancel</option>
                        </select></td>
```

how to do it? any hint please?

Comment: You'd need inline scriptlets like `disabled="<%=something%>"`, JavaEL like `disabled="${something}"` or have different select declarations in your if- and else-branches.

Comment: No, in this case it is always disable no matter something is true or false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<%
        boolean something=false;
        String state = "";
        if(something){
            state = "disabled";
            // here I want to get plc1 using id and want to disable it if it is ture
        }else{
           state = "enable"; 
        }
        %>
```

Html

```
<select <%= state %> id = "plc1" >
```

Now its working Thanks

Answer (score 1):

just use `disabled` attribute: `<select id="plc1" disabled>`

```
<%
    String state = "";
    if(something){
        state = "disabled";
    }
%>

<select id="plc1" <%= state %>>
```

Comment: @FatimaEman I'm using it very often. It should work. Check the html code in your browser. http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_select_disabled.asp

Comment: I have checked in both browsers Mozila and Chrom. they always show enable drop down, no matter something is false or true

Comment: I have use <%= state %> instead of ${state}
Now, its working. thanks